# How to remove old beaker sessions from memcached?

Tags: python, session, memcached, beaker

According to the [beaker documentation](http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sessions.html#removing-expired-old-sessions):

> Beaker does **not** automatically delete expired or old cookies on any of its back-ends. This task is left up to the developer based on how sessions are being used, and on what back-end.

Using [mcinspect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/memcacheinspector/0.2.0) I've found that my memcached instance does seem to be persisting session records for much longer than the session is valid/in use.

What would be the best approach to remove deleted/expired/old/invalid beaker sessions from memcached?

Answer (score 0):

What are you asking, or why are you asking this? Do you mean invalid/old as in your logic, or are they actually expired?

If they are really expired in memcached then they'll be 'gone' for all practical purposes -> they will not be returned and the space is free for new sessions. No need to do anything

If they are old/invalid in some other domain, and you cannot check that, you might need to flush your memcached, but that'll remove all your entries.